# Python 3 print() to a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

In Python 3, you can use the print function to write the data to a file (e.g. `print('my data', file=my_open_file)`. This is well and good (and very cool). But can you `print` to a (string?) variable? If so, how?

In my specific use case, I am trying to avoid writing the data to a tempfile on disk just to turn and read that tempfile.

**Edit:** I'm can't just assign because my source data isn't a string, rather it's part of the html document tree as extracted by BeautifulSoup. Once I have the document tree extracted, I'm going to process it line by line.

---

**My Code**: (working now!)

```
with open("index.html", "r") as soup_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(soup_file)
THE_BODY = soup.find('body')
not_file = io.StringIO()
print(THE_BODY, file = not_file)    # dump the contents of the <body> tag into a file-like stream
with codecs.open('header.js', "w", "utf-8") as HEADER_JS:
    for line in not_file2.getvalue().split('\n'):
        print("headerblock += '{}'".format(line), file = HEADER_JS)
```

---

**Better, Working Code**:

```
with open("index.html", "r") as soup_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(soup_file)
with codecs.open('header.js', "w", "utf-8") as HEADER_JS:
    for line in str(soup.find('body')).split('\n'):
        print("headerblock += '{}'".format(line), file = HEADER_JS)
```

Comment: Why would you not just assign instead?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Maybe you want co capture the output of a function to a string that prints to a file.

Comment: I'm confused as to what the difference is between printing to a string and simply assigning a string. Isn't the end result the same in both cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATED RESPONSE BASED ON UPDATED QUESTION**

If all you need to do is convert your object as a string, simply call the `str` function on the variable... this is what `print` does internally.

```
a = str(soup.find('body'))
```

Calling `print` does a whole bunch of other stuff that you don't need if all you need is a string representation.

---

**ORIGINAL RESPONSE**

You can use [io.StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/io.html?highlight=stringio#text-i-o).

```
import io 
f = io.StringIO()
print('my data', file=f)

# to get the value back
a = f.getvalue()
print(a)
f.close()
```

Note that on python2 this is under `StringIO.StringIO`.

This solution is good for when you have pre-existing code that wants to print to file, but you would rather capture that output in a variable.

Comment: I like this approach, but this changes the 'storage block' from lines to chars. So see above for how I did it :)

Comment: As much as I appreciate the rep, now that I see what you are doing I have to agree with the others that just assigning to a variable is a much simpler solution. I had assumed you needed this for a more complicated reason.

Comment: You could have done `a = str(soup.find('body'))`. `print` just calls `str` internally.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it all the way through. With all your pointers, many of the other comments now make sense, and I was able to simplify my code even more.