# How to store backslash unescaped string in a variable?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, escaping

A lot of questions regarding unescaping strings seem to be related to Python 2 or for unescaping unicode character codes.

I have a string being returned from LDAP that seems to be 'double escaped':

```
>>> escaped = "hello\\,world"
```

I want to unescape this string and store it into another variable, but `decode` doesn't return what I expect:

```
>>> escaped.encode().decode('unicode_escape')
'hello\\,world'
```

The result of a `print()` however returns what I want:

```
>>> print(escaped)
hello\,world
```

I know I can capture the [result of that print to an IO stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27137938/python-3-print-to-a-variable), but surely there is a more elegant solution than that?

Comment: `"hello\\,world"` is not double escaped or even escaped. Try to print it as is you'll see `>>> print("hello\\,world")
hello\,world`. XY problem? what is your real issue?

Comment: I thought that unescaping it once should produce `hello\,world` and then a second time should produce `hello,world`.  Is this not correct?

Comment: escaping takes place when printing the result of the command in a REPL. Always test your results with `print` because that's what will be displayed/stored in files, etc... Where are you unescaping BTW? do you want to unescape?

Comment: I simply want the unescaped value to store for later display.  My understanding of the unescaped value `hello\,world` is that it is still escaped to explicitly show that the comma should not be regarded as part of the LDAP DN string.

Comment: your data actually contains `hello\,world`. using print gives you the contents as displayed, using return value in REPL gives you the value that you can paste back in python which explains there's a double "\\"

Comment: Okay, so how do I get that unescaped display value in a string?  That will be the answer to this question.

Comment: the proper value is already in the string... try `escaped = "hello\\,world";
for c in escaped:
    print(c)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'hello\\world'` is not doubly escaped - it is simply that when showing the internal representation (aka "repr") of strings, Python *does* escape backslashes so that you, the person viewing this representation know that `\\` represent an actual, single, backslash character inside the string, and not a escape sequence for another character.

When you call `print`, the string representation is done through another method, which is meant for program output - i.e. for the users of the program to consume. On this representation, the "\" is properly rendered as "\", and other sequences, such as "\n", "\t", "\b" are rendered as the real characters they represent ("\x0a", "\x09" and "\x07" in this case - or "LINE FEED", "TAB" and "BACKSPACE").

The former is rendered by Python through the call of the `__repr__` method in any object, and it is what any Python interactive environment uses to show the result of expressions. The later rendering, used by `print` takes place calling an object's `__str__` method instead. In code, instead of calling these methods directly, one should call respectively the built-ins `repr(...)` and `str(...)`.

Also, by using f-strings it is easy to interpolate the desired view of an object in another text-snippet. If you want the "str" view, just place the object as an expression between `{}` inside the f-string. If the internal representation is desired, before the closing `}`, include the `!r` sequence:

```py
In [192]: a = "Hello\world!"                                                                                             

In [193]: a                                                                                                              
Out[193]: 'Hello\\world!'

In [194]: print(a)                                                                                                       
Hello\world!

In [195]: print(repr(a))                                                                                                 
'Hello\\world!'

In [196]: print(f"*{a}*{a!r}*")                                                                                          
*Hello\world!*'Hello\\world!'*
```

As you can see, even typing a single "\", if the character following it does not form a known escape sequence, the "\" is taken alone - but shown as "\", because we, humans, are in no obligation to know by heart which are valid escape sequences and which are not. On the other hand, typing a single "\" meaning a backlash in literal strings is quite dangerous, as there is a big chance of creating an unintended other character. In Python 3.8 (currently in beta), this even yields syntax warning:

```
Python 3.8.0b2+ (heads/3.8:028f1d2479, Jul 17 2019, 22:42:16) 
[GCC 9.1.1 20190503 (Red Hat 9.1.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = "hello\world!"
<stdin>:1: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence \w
```

The way to avoid this warning is to either always type a double `\\` or use the `r'` prefix for the string:

```
>>> a = r"hello\world!"
```

Comment: I originally came back here thinking that I may delete this question, because I'd made a fundamental mistake.  However this question and answer may serve to inform for others having the same misunderstanding such as myself and your answer, particularly explaining `str` and `repr` while also mentioning f strings is fantastic.  Thank you. What better problem to have than one which is solved by virtue of it not being a problem in the first place!