How to remove backslash from a very long string?
I have a string with more than 3000 characters and I have a couple of backslash that I want to remove, but none of the methods I tried worked.
When I tried to remove the backslash from an example substring there is no problem:
temp01 = "AS DATE FORMAT \'YYYY-MM-YY\'"
temp02 = ''.join(char for char in temp01 if char !="\\")
temp02
AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-YY'

but the same replacement for that substring inside the big string does not work.
I also tried with replace, same results.
What can I use to replace the backslash?

there are precisely 0 backslashes in temp01. That is the problem here. In general, the approach you want is temp02 = temp01.sub('\\', '') if you want to remove all instances of some character from a string, although, the code you showed would work as well (although, it will be less efficient and you should just use str builtins where you can)

temp01 does not actually contain any backslashes.  Both were interpreted as escape sequences at the time the code was executed.

There are no backslashes in the string. The backslashes are part of the literal syntax to escape the single quotes. Note that it's not actually necessary to escape them, since double quotes are used to delimit the string.

what may be occuring is that somewhere, you have a string where the repr(my_string) will have escape sequences (although, that isn't the case with the example you gave above). Note, if you have, say, a str in a list, and then print the list, you will get the repr of the items in the list.

Note that you would get backslashes if you used a raw string: temp01 = r"AS DATE FORMAT \'YYYY-MM-YY\'"

There is no reason why this should work differently for strings shorter than 3000 characters and for longer strings.

so, for example, if we do: temp01 = "AS \"foo\"  DATE FORMAT \'YYYY-MM-YY\'", this str object also doesn't contain any backslashes (try print(temp01)), however, if you do print(repr(temp01)) or print([temp01]) you'll see backslashes, but they aren't in the actual string

@mkrieger1 I don't think the length is the issue in the code, it's just a reason why he doesn't post it in the [mre].

I think this answer explains the double vs single backslash in code at length  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57195655/how-to-store-backslash-unescaped-string-in-a-variable/57204164#57204164 - not marking as a duplicate, as it is a different question. The O.P. here should just use "str.replace".

Thank you very much for your answers, you were all right!
My intention was to use that string to execute a query in a database and I thought that the backslash was going to be interpreted as literal character within the query, hence the intention to eliminate it, but as many mentioned, that backslash 'does not exist' in reality.
Sorry if I didn't include a complete example, but all of this was taking place in a virtual machine that doesn't even have copy and paste enabled, so I only copied a few lines by hand.
